# Program an iOS app to launch itself at specific times

Tags: ios

I'm developing a medical alert and record keeping app for iOS for a client. The app needs to be able to open itself at specific times based on a schedule that is set remotely.

I've searched around for how this can be done, and I keep running into other apps that let you schedule app launch times, but this needs to be a self contained solution.

I'd rather not JailBreak the iOS device to make it work, and I've come across articles that say iOS 9+ now has this capacity, but no instructions on how to make it come about.

Any clues, tutorials, or other information on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there a reason the app itself needs to open and you can't just send the user a push notification at that interval?

Comment: @AdamPro13 all I can say is it's how the client is asking for it.

Comment: Why does the app need to launch itself? What is it supposed to do when its launched? As mentioned this is not possible (silent pushes will not work in all circumstances). But if the point of the app launching is so the user can notice it, then a foreground push is the way to go instead. You need to take a step back and ask the client why they are asking for it, what is the motivation behind the requirement, and then look for a solution to solve the requirement given iOS's restrictions.

Comment: The requirement specifically set by the client is "if they're watching Netflix or something, their media needs to pause and automatically switch to our app, like it would if someone were getting a phone call".

Comment: That requirement can't be met. You cannot force your app to the foreground.

Comment: 1. What you're describing is not possible unless the device is jailbroken. It's a terrible user experience. 2. I'm not sure what exactly your client is trying to do, but the friction involved in installing an app like this would be so high that there's no way they'd reach any decent level of distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["silent" push notifications (with "content-available")](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) on iOS 7+ to launch the app when the push notification is received on the device. You will get a chance to process the notification, and the app will be launched if it's not already running.

However, it still won't work if the user has force killed the app.

Also, iOS will not launch your app if it feels you've gone over the daily processing time or data quota.

Comment: How do I know what the daily processing time or data quotas are?

Comment: The quotas are undefined and decided by Apple.